# Populating textbox's from a database using the same form with asp classic

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

anyone know if there is a way to populate the original form textboxes from ms access database using classic asp.  After I find a record, I want the fields to populate the textboxes of the form, I do not want to create new textboxes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, you made me dig for a 10 year old project :-)

I understood your question as follows: You have a classic ASP web page, this page contains some form fields. On the server side, you search for some record and then you want to display the found data in the fields of the page. Right?

Here's what I did a long time ago (snippet):

```
Set rstSample = myDB.execute("SELECT * FROM tblSample WHERE tblSample.sample_id = 1;"
If rstSample.BOF = False Then
  If Len(rstSample("sample_name")) > 0 Then v_name = Server.HTMLEncode(rstSample("sample_name"))
End If
rstSample.close

...

<input type="text" name="myName" value="<%=v_name%>">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am using similar code in my program   <input type = text name="txtEmployeeID" VALUE="<%=objRS("userid")%>">.                                         This code creates another text box. I want to populate the same text box I used for input to search. Once the record is found I want to populate the same text box with the output.

Comment: I would then check if the page is loaded for the first time or if there's a request.form:
**a.** if loaded for the first time: request.form("myName") will be empty >> set v_name="" >> the input field will be empty and ready for user input.
**b.** if request.form("myName") has a value (>> the user put in some data and hit submit), use it to find your search result and then assign the result to v_name >> the **same** input field will present the result.